# Area of a surface that is a graph of a function

Tags: differential-geometry, area, surfaces

Let $h: (0,1) \times (0,1)->\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, and let $S=\{(u,v,h(u,v))| u,v \in (0,1)\}$. Determine the differentiable functions $h$ for which the area of $S$ is $1$.

We know that the area of $S$ is $\int_{(0,1) \times (0,1)} ((\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial u})^2+(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial v})^2+1)^ \frac{1}{2} dudv$ but know how can i resolve the problem?

Comment: Hint: What is a lower bound for this area? What must the derivatives of $h$ be to attain this lower bound?

Comment: we have that the area of $S$ is $\ge 1$

Comment: i think $(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial u})^2+(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial v})^2=0$? (i.e. $\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial u}=0$ and $\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial v}=0$)

Comment: Yes, and when does that happen?

Comment: but i don t know i mean, the integral can be $1$ also if $(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial u})^2+(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial v})^2 \neq 0$?

Comment: If that sum isn't zero, then it is positive and the integrand is $\sqrt{1+\text{positive}} > 1$

Comment: You mean $\int_{(0,1) \times (0,1)} ((\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial u})^2+(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial v})^2+1)^ \frac{1}{2} dudv>\int_{(0,1) \times (0,1)}1 dudv=1$ if $(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial u})^2+(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial v})^2 \neq 0$